# SQL - text functions not working (Reverse/Left/Substring/LTrim) - gotta be easy

Tags: sql, sql-server, text

I've got a text field on a table that I'm trying to dissect into two separate columns in a select statement.  I swear this worked for me last time I used it, but now it's throwing an error "Invalid length parameter".  What am I doing wrong?

Splitting the data from a single column which is like this:

"CORP - DIVISION - REGION - TEAM - SUPERVISOR"

Into two columns like:

SUPERVISOR | TEAM

Here's what I had that I swear used to work, but it doesn't anymore and I can't figure it out!

```
Reverse(Left(Reverse(table.column),CHARINDEX(' ', Reverse(table.column))-1)) AS 'SUPERVISOR'
,LTRIM(LEFT(Substring(table.column,18,150),CHARINDEX(' - ', Substring(table.column,18,150))-1)) AS 'TEAM'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Works for me

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48ce825909133842c113193e3da5ebea

Comment: I'll bet you have a value in that column that doesn't contain a space, or doesn't contain `' - '` between the 18th and the 150th char.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - you are exactly right.  I scrubbed the data and found some sneaky bast@rd has a "&" in their label.  ...  hrrrmmmmmm....  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a known or maximum number of items, consider a little XML.  Perhaps a little easier to read and maintain.

Also, you could eliminate Pos1,Pos2,Pos3 if you are only interested in Team & Supervisor.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'CORP - DIVISION - REGION - TEAM - SUPERVISOR')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')))  
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(100)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(SomeCol,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1    Pos2        Pos3    Pos4    Pos5        Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9
1   CORP    DIVISION    REGION  TEAM    SUPERVISOR  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**EDIT**

If you have non XML safe characters (<,>,,...) use

```
...
From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(SomeCol,'-','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
...
```

Comment: Of course, that's a good **workaround**... the solution would be to normalize the data....

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agree 100%.   I've had to consume some horrible data from external sources (as I'm sure you have too)   :)

Comment: This is great @JohnCappelletti!  I'm bookmarking this to use later.  Thank you.  But I agree with you both, data normalization would benefit these data the best, unfortunately that is out of my control.  So now to figure out a workaround

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2016 you can use **STRING_SPLIT()** to do it.

> The STRING_SPLIT() can help normalize the data by splitting these
> multi-valued columns.

I also used TRIM() function (introduced with SQL Server 2017) in order to remove the spaces, CTE, ROW_NUMBER() and PIVOT.

Below the script:

```
—-1 Create a test table
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(
    TestColumn varchar(100)
)

—-2 Inserting your string into table
INSERT INTO #TestTable
VALUES ('0 - CORP - DIVISION - REGION - TEAM - SUPERVISOR')

--3 Final query
;WITH CTE_Table AS (
 SELECT
     TestColumn = TRIM(TestColumn)
 FROM
     #TestTable
 )
 ,CTE_Table2 AS (
 SELECT
     S.Value 
 FROM 
     CTE_Table
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([TestColumn],'-') AS S
 )
 ,CTE_FinalTable AS (
 SELECT TOP 5
    Value
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) AS RowNumber
 FROM
    CTE_Table2
 ORDER BY
    Value
)
SELECT 
    [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
FROM
   CTE_FinalTable
PIVOT 
   (MAX([value])
The FOR [RowNumber] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) AS P
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestColumn ORDER BY TestColumn)` will return an arbitrary row number. It's basically order by a constant since in every partition you get exactly one distinct value to use for sorting.

Comment: I changed the script. Thanks

Comment: Any news about it?